# Toggle iOS NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar with TabbedPage results in hiding the tabs

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

Anyone tried this scenario before? I'm talking about latest Xamarin forms 2 targetting iOS.

I have a TabbedPage with 4 tabs, when the user looks at the first 2, there should not be a navigationbar - I got this working by setting the NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false) in the constructor of the TabbedPage.

Now by using the ExtendedTabbedPage of Xamarin forms labs, I can hook up to the change tab event called OnCurrentPageChanged() and in here I verify if I'm on one of the last 2 tabs and toggle the NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true).

This actually works great, except for 1 small detail. When the navigation bar gets shown, tab page shifts down and it hides the tabs at the bottom, so the user is unable to switch tabs at that moment.

When I set NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true) in the constructor of the tabbedpage and leave it for all tabs, the result is ok. Meaning I get a navigationheader and tabs visible on each tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found a solution myself.

So the original setup was as follows, in the App.xaml.cs I initiated the Navigation through following code

```
NavigationPage navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

MainPage is a TabbedPage containing several children.
What I did was toggling the NavigationBar of that MainPage when switching from one child page to another

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
```

But that resulted in the child pages not being resized, leaving the tabbar at the bottom of the page invisible when the navigationbar came visible.

So the actual solution is to not set the MainPage as a NavigationPage, but wrap each child in a NavigationPage!
This way each child can have it's own NavigationBar an that keeps the size in reference to the MainPage correct.
So adding each child would be like this

```
this.Children.Add (new NavigationPage (new DiscoverPage ()){ Title = "Discover" });
```

Took me a while to figure this out because I normally would add the children inside the actual xaml of the MainPage but that way you can't wrap them in a NavigationPage, hence why I wrapped the MainPage itself inside the NavigationPage!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, by any chance do you have a more complete example?. Your answer helped me a lot, but It's happening to me now that for the two tab children that I have, only one is being displayed.

Comment: Not sure what I could add more... this is what I do in the constructor of the main page and that will just render the tabs: `public MainPage ()
{
 InitializeComponent ();

 this.Children.Add (new NavigationPage (new DiscoverPage ()){ Title = "Discover" });
 this.Children.Add (new NavigationPage (new NewsPage ()){ Title = "News" });
 this.Children.Add (new NavigationPage (new EventsPage ()){ Title = "Events" });
 this.Children.Add (new NavigationPage (new CameraPage ()){ Title = "Camera" });
}`

Answer (score 0):

It could be some bug in computing correct size of tabbed page in NavigationPage when toggling NavagationBar visibility. 
In order that I need that tabbed page must be in NavigationPage I came up with the next solution:

```
public class BaseNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
    public BaseNavigationPage() : base()
    {
        this.BarTextColor = Color.White;
    }

    public BaseNavigationPage(Page page) : base(page)
    {
        this.BarTextColor = Color.White;
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if (propertyName == nameof(CurrentPage))
        {
            Current = CurrentPage;
        }
    }

    private void CurrentPage_PropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == NavigationPage.HasNavigationBarProperty.PropertyName && _bounds == Rectangle.Zero)
        {
            _bounds = CurrentPage.Bounds;
        }
    }

    private void Current_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == NavigationPage.HasNavigationBarProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var has = NavigationPage.GetHasNavigationBar(CurrentPage);
            if (has)
            {
                CurrentPage.Layout(_bounds);
                _bounds = Rectangle.Zero;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentPage.Layout(this.Bounds);
            }
        }
    }

    private Page Current
    {
        get { return _current; }
        set
        {
            if (_current != null)
            {
                _current.PropertyChanging -= CurrentPage_PropertyChanging;
                _current.PropertyChanged -= Current_PropertyChanged;
            }
            _current = value;
            if (_current != null)
            {
                _current.PropertyChanging += CurrentPage_PropertyChanging;
                _current.PropertyChanged += Current_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private Page _current;
    private Rectangle _bounds;
}
```

And use may BaseNavigationPage instead of NavigationPage and all works fine.